# Woocommerce move out of stock to bottom

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

Using *"[Show Out of stock products at the end in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113581/show-out-of-stock-products-at-the-end-in-woocommerce/44597448#44597448)"* answer code from **@DACrosby** does what it should, **except that there is a conflict with Woocommerce latest version** when creating a new product 'auto saved draft' will not be shown if you skip the page.

Does anyone experience the same problem - have a solution? - I couldn't find any