# Show out of stock products - targets custom post types

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to sort my out of stock products at the end.
It works, but the query that I found by DACrosby also target custom post types.
[Show Out of stock products at the end in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113581/show-out-of-stock-products-at-the-end-in-woocommerce/)

This is the original code:

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status');
function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    // only change query on WooCommerce loops
    if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())) {
        $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
        $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```

When I monitor my query I see this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1
ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations wpml_translations
ON wp_posts.ID = wpml_translations.element_id
AND wpml_translations.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta istockstatus
ON (wp_posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status'
AND istockstatus.meta_value <> ''
OR wp_posts.post_type = 'gp_elements'
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1816)
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
SELECT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (10) )
AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1816) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
AND ( ( ( wpml_translations.language_code = 'nl'
OR ( wpml_translations.language_code = 'nl'
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ( 'gp_elements' )
AND ( ( (
SELECT COUNT(element_id)
FROM wp_icl_translations
WHERE trid = wpml_translations.trid
AND language_code = 'nl' ) = 0 )
OR ( (
SELECT COUNT(element_id)
FROM wp_icl_translations t2 JOIN wp_posts p
ON p.id = t2.element_id
WHERE t2.trid = wpml_translations.trid
AND t2.language_code = 'nl'
AND ( p.post_status = 'publish'
OR p.post_type='attachment'
AND p.post_status = 'inherit' ) ) = 0 ) ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','product','product_variation','gp_elements' ) )
OR wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','wp_block','product','product_variation','gp_elements' ) )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY istockstatus.meta_value ASC, wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

As you can see it also targets gp_elements which is a custom post type of my theme.
Since the where doesn't include it, it doesn't show up on my pages.

Any tips how to include it back on my page and keeping the sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "[GeneratePress](https://generatepress.com/)"?

It appears that they register a custom post type called `gp_elements`.

Since your filter function runs on the `posts_clauses` hook, it's operating alongside other functions that have been hooked there. I don't think you're seeing this custom post type targted as a result of the `order_by_stock_status` function.

The quick check is to switch themes (and/or possibly deactivate a generatepress related plugin), and monitor your query again. I bet it dissappears.

Additionally, and luckily, the `WHERE` clause in that query *should* be evaluating true for those products with non-empty stock statuses and ignoring the `gp_elements` criteria. I've bracketed this excerpt to make the order of operations clearer. So perhaps you could also examine the data itself to ensure you've got `_stock_status` metakeys with values to be compared/sorted by.

```
// ...
WHERE (
   1=1
   AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status'
   AND istockstatus.meta_value <> ''
 )
 OR wp_posts.post_type = 'gp_elements'`
```

(Unhooking the generatepress function that's filtering on the `posts_clauses` hook is possible, of course, but it'll also come with its own set of problems.)

Edit: Per your comment, if you want to go the other way and add your clauses only sometimes (not to get in the way of GeneratePress' header) you might try conditionally filtering, based on the query. You may need to unhook this function before the headers are called; hard to say without seeing the internals of GP.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sometimes_add_filter');

function sometimes_add_filter($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() {
        add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm ideed using generatepress. There is a elements module that displays custom headers. When I run the code above the header code is filtered out. And I want it back on my page. 

Since I cannot adjust the query itself it need to be done in the code.
Any hlep for that?

Comment: Updated with an additional approach

Comment: Great thanks for the update. But this will only do the query if it's not admin?
The query can run anytime. I only want to see the GP_elements as well.
These are filtered out by the code. So I think we need to add the GP_Elements to the where clause in the php code. I just can't figure out how to target it.