# WooCommerce's filter product sorting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show in stock product is first then show out of stock in product and order by acf 'sorting' filed. And I used the plugin WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter for filter.

I used pre_get_posts at first

```
function specific_category( $query ) {
    if ( (is_product_category() && $query->is_main_query()) || (is_shop() && $query->is_main_query()) ) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'sorting');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
} add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'specific_category' );
```

For sorting used from [Show Out of stock products at the end in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113581/show-out-of-stock-products-at-the-end-in-woocommerce/67681898#67681898)

```
function order_by_stock_status( $posts_clauses, $query ) {
            // only change query on WooCommerce loops
            if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() || is_shop() ) ) {
                global $wpdb;
        
                $posts_clauses['join'] .= 
                " LEFT JOIN ( 
                    SELECT post_id, meta_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                    WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value <> '' 
                ) istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
                $posts_clauses['orderby'] = 
                " CASE istockstatus.meta_value WHEN 
                    'outofstock' THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            }
            return $posts_clauses;
}add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status', 2000, 2 );
```

It worked!

But the problem is after change the page of products and load ajax, the sorting(show instock first then out of stock) is not working!!!
Please answer for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer.
If you want to work **posts_clauses** after change the page of products and load Ajax, have to add condition in if statement of function order_by_stock_status.

what I added is

```
if ( ($query->is_main_query() && ( is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy() || is_shop())) || ( $query->get('orderby') != 'date') )
```